# How to make only one radio button selected and remaining unselected in listview in android?

Tags: android

I need to create radio buttons in listview. I need to select any one only in that list view items. For example if I select the radio button of listitem 2 and then again if i select listitem 3 then list item 2 which is selected should be disabled. How could I do thatin listview?

Any suggestion will be helpful....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change your ListView Adapter when you click on ListView Item (setup the OnItemClickListener for ListView).

When you change adapter you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() for your ListView object

Hope, it hel you!